# Understanding Execution of Chef Runlists to All Nodes?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, configuration-management

### Background

I have most of my environment set up with my self-hosted chef-server, target nodes and workstation. I've bootstrapped my nodes with run-lists and followed the setup to get them registered with the chef-server.

### What I Want

I want to be able to say, at any given moment, go run X run-list to all the nodes that have the run-list attached to them. How can I do this in one command? It's not clear to me in the documentation how I actually tell the server to execute a run-list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't generally run a recipe as an operation. Chef is built around the idea of convergent design. So you can manually kick off `chef-client` via `knife ssh` or some other push-based command runner (RunDeck, SaltStack, MCollective, etc), and/or use the daemon mode to run a converge every N seconds. In either case, you're just triggering a run of whatever the run list for the node is, which is stored in Chef Server. We do have the `--override-runlist` option but it is generally something to avoid except in very specific circumstances.